# Mixed Content: The page at {URL} was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint {ENDPOINT}

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have the following projects https://github.com/codyc4321/dividends_ui and https://github.com/codyc4321/stocks_backend. The deployed app at https://octopus-app-8l8j5.ondigitalocean.app/ is getting error

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://octopus-app-8l8j5.ondigitalocean.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://67.205.161.47:8000/dividends/wba'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is the error I got last week but now I have gone through and done https://timonweb.com/django/https-django-development-server-ssl-certificate/ and am running the python server with https:

```
root@username:~/stocks_backend# python3 manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem
```

I do not understand why my app isn't working for the request, although I notice that BEFORE using the cert file I could hit an endpoint from my local machine just fine, and now after it my local machine gets `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 67.205.161.47:8000`

I made the key file as such

```
mkcert -cert-file cert.pem -key-file key.pem octopus-app-8l8j5.ondigitalocean.app octopus-app-8l8j5 ondigitalocean.app
```

Why running the server using cert and key files for https not sufficient to make this API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line in your App.js [file](https://github.com/codyc4321/dividends_ui/blob/a78312e3d23ec2f42c7de193fa096bdf86f6ab89/src/components/App.js) in dividends_ui

```
const base_url = 'http://' + HOST + ':8000'
```

I have a suspicion this is failing because, when the URL it constructs is called, it is calling an http URL from within an https environment, which is a security risk.

If the HOST domain is always going to be using https, then changing it to

```
const base_url = 'https://' + HOST + ':8000'
```

should do the trick.  If you're are not sure, then

```
const base_url = '//' + HOST + ':8000'
```

can solve the problem as it will use the protocol of the calling page but, obviously, explicitly using https is usually the best method.

Comment: `GET https://67.205.161.47:8000/dividends/wba net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: let me see how to check server logs

Comment: running server again with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 dividends_project.wsgi
` I get timeout error `AxiosError {message: 'timeout exceeded', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ECONNABORTED', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest}`